# Have I found a bug in Wolfram Alpha's Partial Derivative Solver?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wolfram-alpha, derivatives

I was using [This Wolfram Alpha Page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d/da%20a%2aexp%28-%28%28x-b%29%5E2/2c%5E2%29%29%20%2b%20d%2aexp%28-%28%28x-g%29%5E2/2h%5E2%29%29) to calculate the partial derivatives of the sum of two gaussians. It believes the answer to be: 
$$
e^{-(b-x)^2/2 c^2}
$$
but the working shows it as ending on:
$$
e^{-(x-b)^2/2 c^2}
$$
Which is what I had thought the answer was.

Is this a bug in Wolfram's engine or have I missed an obvious step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It:$$(x-b)^{2} = (b-x)^{2} \ \ \forall b,x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Of course, complete brain-fart over here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> have I missed an obvious step?

[Yes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28-%28b-x%29%5E2/%282%20c%5E2%29%29%20=%20e%5E%28-%28x-b%29%5E2/%282%20c%5E2%29%29)